# Substring text of a textbox and datetime picker to a maskbox

Tags: c#, winforms, substring

I use to generate the permanent code with a button after I entered everything.
like so:

```
mskCodePer.Text =
    txtNom.Text.Substring(0, 3) +    
    txtPrenom.Text.Substring(0, 1) + 
    dptNaisc.Text.Substring(8, 2) + 
    dptNaisc.Text.Substring(4, 4) + 
    dptNaisc.Text.Substring(2, 3);
```

But my teacher force me to do it in a way that it happens automatically as I type, but I don't understand how.

I tried to code into the textchanged event but each time I only get to type one letter, it crashes and tells me an ArgumentOutOfRangeException has been generated.

Comment: You're right when use textchanged event, but you don't add the check for the length of `mskCodePer.Text`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.95).aspx) eventfor these textboxes.

Separate `maskbox` text update code in a separate method and invoke this function/method for every `TextBox` text change.

```
public void UpdateMask()
{
    mskCodePer.Text =
    (txtNom.Text!=null && txtNom.Text.Length > 2)? txtNom.Text.Substring(0, 3): string.Empty +
    (txtPrenom.Text!=null && txtPrenom.Text.Length > 0)? txtPrenom.Text.Substring(0, 1): string.Empty +    
    (dptNaisc.Text!=null && dptNaisc.Text.Length > 9)? dptNaisc.Text.Substring(8, 2): string.Empty +    
    (dptNaisc.Text!=null && dptNaisc.Text.Length > 7)? dptNaisc.Text.Substring(4, 4): string.Empty +    
    (dptNaisc.Text!=null && dptNaisc.Text.Length > 5)? dptNaisc.Text.Substring(2, 3): string.Empty ;    
}


// keep below logic in form_load or relevant event.

txtNom.TextChanged += (s,e) => {UpdateMask();}
txtPrenom.TextChanged += (s,e) => {UpdateMask();}
dptNaisc.TextChanged += (s,e) => {UpdateMask();}
```